# import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, greendao

I've copied ExampleDaoGenerator.java as ExampleDaoGenerator2.java 
and modeled for my schema database and table.

I have kept ExampleDaoGenerator2.java file from the folder:

`C:\Backup\495704\My Documents\Downloads\gitHub\greenDAO-master`

However I'm getting the import error in my eclipse

I also added freemarker-2.3.20.jar file in my JRE path:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib`
and configured project's build path.

But I'm not able to see freemarker-2.3.20.jar under note `JRE System Library [jre6]` in the `Libraries` tab of the `Java Build Path` dialog.

Can you please let me know what is missing?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634219/greendao-freemaker-jar-is-missing

Comment: I have resolved the issue, by taking the required DAOGenerator-1.3.0.jar file from Maven and added as referenced library. This is not available in the zip file of github

Comment: yeah, makes sense given that they're building with gradle, which will just pull that jar automatically. glad you got it working